# What is the smallest group containing $f$ and $g$ isomorphic to?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $f,g : A=\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0,1\} \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined as:

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}, \ g(x)=\frac{x-1}{x} $$

The smallest group of functions from $A$ to $\mathbb{R}$ containing $f,g$ under composition is isomorphic to which group?

I tried a few things like finding the inverse of $f,g, f \circ g$, etc. This just got me to suspect that it is possibly of infinite order.

Comment: The group law is pointwise addition of functions?

Comment: @goblin Composition

Comment: Functions $A\to \mathbb{R}$ don't form a group under composition. It's not even a monoid : the composition $g\circ f$ is undefined (and neither is $f\circ g$).

Comment: Please confirm that you mean $A = \mathbb R \setminus \{0,1\}$.

Comment: @lhf Sorry for the late reply. Yes that is what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably mean $A = \mathbb R \setminus \{0,1\}$.
In this case, 
$f$ and $g$ define functions $A \to A$ and so it makes sense to talk about the group they generate.

We get
$$
f^2 = id, \quad g^3 = id, \quad gf = fg^2
$$
Therefore, it's the dihedral group $D_{6}$, the group of symmetries of a regular triangle, aka as $S_3$.

Comment: Isn't $g^3 =1$?

Comment: $f$ and $g$ *don't* define functions $A\to A$. Both of them map $2\in A$ to $\frac{1}{2}\notin A$.

Comment: That makes more sense. It would be nice if OP could confirm though, just to be sure.

Comment: I still get $g^3=1$.

Comment: @lhf I suppose PJK meant that the triple composition of the original function $g\colon A\to \Bbb R$ is the identity map. Your matrix with the same name is a different matter. The rational function defined by the negative identity matrix is the identity.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, oh I see. You're quite right, of course. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than considering these as functions on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0, 1\}$, we can extend them to functions defined on $\newcommand{\P}{\mathbb{P}} \newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}} \P^1(\R) = \R \cup \{\infty\}$.  We then see that the group $G$ generated by $f$ and $g$ acts on the three points $0,1, \infty$ as permutations:
\begin{align*}
f: 0 &\mapsto \infty\\
1 &\mapsto 1\\
\infty &\mapsto 0
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
g: 0 &\mapsto \infty\\
\infty &\mapsto 1\\
1 &\mapsto 0
\end{align*}
so $f$ corresponds to the transposition $(0, \infty)$ and $g$ to the $3$-cycle $(0, \infty, 1)$.  These two permutations generate the symmetric group $S_3$, and since a Möbius transformation is determined by where it sends any $3$ points, then $G \cong S_3$.

As a note, the $\P^1(\R)$ is the boundary of the completed complex upper half-plane $\mathcal{H}^*$.  The automorphism group of $\mathcal{H}^*$ is $\mathrm{PSL}_2(\R)$, which explains the small error in lhf's answer pointed out by PJK and Hagen von Eitzen: $\mathrm{PSL}_2(\R) = \mathrm{SL}_2(\R)/\{\pm I\}$, so $-I$ acts by the identity as well.